# redirect part of url if query-var exists

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, typo3, realurl

I have relaunched a TYPO3 Website and have a problem with the redirects of old links listed by google. I want to redirect this:

```
https://www.mydomain.ac/index.php?id=88&itemID=123
```

to

```
https://www.mydomain.ac/item/item-detail/?itemID=123
```

The id 88 is fix. It still does not exists in the new site, but maybe can be added later. So I just want to redirect if the id=88 **AND** an itemID (any number) is in the URL. I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?id=88&itemID= /item/item-detail/?itemID= [L]
```

but this didn't work ... obviously ;-)

Any idea how to solve this?
Thanx in advance!

Comment: RewriteRule checks on the _path_ component of the URL only - if you want to check the query string for anything, you have to use a RewriteCond for that.

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanx for the comment. I found a similar solution like the answer of András posted below. But please remember: there ain't silly questions, just silly answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a RewriteCond too.

You can test it here: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=88&itemID=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.mydomain.ac/item/item-detail/?itemID=%1 [L]
```

Comment: @A.Tietz: You are welcome! If the answer helped, could you pls accept it as the correct answer, to help others too! :)

Comment: I changed the RewriteCondition a little bit: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=88&itemID=(.*)?$ [NC] I don't know why, but yours didn't work with all given IDs. Anyway, how can I accept it as the correct answer? I clicked the up-arrow, is there anything else?